# I have a small game in which the round PLAYER has to reach the round EXIT. The Switch inside While loop does not execute. VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, while-loop, switch-statement

I have a small game in which the round **PLAYER** has to reach the round **EXIT**. I have a Switch inside a While loop for reading directions through **PROMPT**. If I remove the While loop, the switch executes as it should, only I have to restart it manually. With the While loop, it's broken!

This is the **HTML** with the **VanillaJs** script.
The issue is, with the While loop in place Switch does not move the Player, console.log reads the right result though.

CodePen :
https://codepen.io/cornel777/pen/vYGxgEB

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Escape</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="RPG.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1  id="title">Escape!!!</h1>

  <div class="board">
    <div id="player"></div>
    <div id="exitRound"></div>
    <div id="exitTriang"></div>
    <div id="exitSquare"></div>
  </div>


<button onclick="play()" class="restart">START</button>

<script>
    // var board = document.getElementById("board");
    var player = document.getElementById("player");
    // var exit1 = document.getElementById("exitTriang");
    var exit2 = document.getElementById("exitRound");
    // var exit3 = document.getElementById("exitSquare");
// play();
    function play() {

        confirm('ready?');

        var posT = player.offsetTop;
        var posL = player.offsetLeft;
        var posT1 = exit2.offsetTop;
        var posL1 = exit2.offsetLeft;
        var x = player.offsetParent;

        console.log(posT, posL, posT1, posL1);
        console.log("offsetParent is " + x + "because it has position css property, otherwise it is body");



        while (posT !== posT1 && posL !== posL1) {
            console.log(posT !== posT1 && posL !== posL1);
            var direction = prompt("Enter direction:\n left, right, up, down");

            switch (direction) {
                case 'left':
                    player.style.left = (posL - 50) + 'px';
                    console.log(player.style.left = (posL - 50) + 'px');
                    break;
                case 'right':
                    player.style.left = (posL + 50) + 'px';
                    break;
                case 'up':
                    player.style.top = (posT - 50) + 'px';
                    break;
                case 'down':
                    player.style.top = (posT + 50) + 'px';
                    break;
                default:
                    alert("you need to move!");
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (posT === posT1 && posL === posL1) {
            alert("YOU WIN!!!");
        }
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One of the conditions in posT !== posT1 && posL !== posL1 must be returning false, can you include your whole html file so that it is easier to debug?

Comment: Actually no, I have a console log and it is true, the reason for which I am stuck in the loop with no way to reach the ROUND EXIT, because it will not move the player as it should. IF I remove the while statement it will work perfectly,  but I have to press the START button every time I want to give a new command. See CodePen

Comment: @Terminat, your deleted response was about right, with the only bug that it stored a direction in advance without action, and thus was a command behind the current one.

Comment: yeah, I noticed this bug, and that's why I've deleted this, because I had not time to debug. Sorry! :D

Comment: @Terminat, do you have any idea why it does that? Any clue would help, I'm trying to make it work.

Comment: I believe it is the issue with how you get an input. The prompt blocks every interaction with the browser so that might be an issue. You can try to get an input via input field and a button to submit a move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of how JavaScript actually works. JavaScript is single-threaded and this means it has only one call stack. Your while loop was blocking this call stack never letting the browser to "repaint" the dom, with the updated value of the red ball.

However there is a method on the window object, that informs the browser that you wish to perfom the animation. It is `window.requestAnimationFrame()`

Now we need to restructure your code a little.

Let's create extract your game logic from play function into gameLoop function

```js
function gameLoop() {
  var posT = player.offsetTop;
  var posL = player.offsetLeft;
  var posT1 = exit2.offsetTop;
  var posL1 = exit2.offsetLeft;
  var x = player.offsetParent;

  var direction = prompt("Enter direction:\n left, right, up, down");
  switch (direction) {
    case 'left':
      player.style.left = (posL - 50) + 'px';
      console.log(player.style.left = (posL - 50) + 'px');
      break;
    case 'right':
      player.style.left = (posL + 50) + 'px';
      break;
    case 'up':
      player.style.top = (posT - 50) + 'px';
      break;
    case 'down':
      player.style.top = (posT + 50) + 'px';
      break;
    default:
      alert("you need to move!");
      break;
  }
  if (posT === posT1 && posL === posL1) {
    alert("YOU WIN!!!");
    return; // gets out of a loop
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
```

Take a closer look at the end of the function. Here I am using the window.requestAnimationFrame to call gameLoop function, to make an actual loop here. And when the condition of winning the game is met, the return inside if statement will stop the loop.

```js
if (posT === posT1 && posL === posL1) {
  alert("YOU WIN!!!");
  return; // gets out of a loop
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
```

And the last thing is the play function, now it is just starting a loop with `window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop)`

```js
    function play() {
      confirm('ready?');
      window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
    }
```

And this is the whole code:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Escape</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="RPG.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="title">Escape!!!</h1>

  <div class="board">
    <div id="player"></div>
    <div id="exitRound"></div>
    <div id="exitTriang"></div>
    <div id="exitSquare"></div>
  </div>

  <button onclick="play()" class="restart">START</button>

  <script>
    // var board = document.getElementById("board");
    var player = document.getElementById("player");
    // var exit1 = document.getElementById("exitTriang");
    var exit2 = document.getElementById("exitRound");
    // var exit3 = document.getElementById("exitSquare");
    // play();
    function play() {
      confirm('ready?');
      window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
    }

    function gameLoop() {
      var posT = player.offsetTop;
      var posL = player.offsetLeft;
      var posT1 = exit2.offsetTop;
      var posL1 = exit2.offsetLeft;
      var x = player.offsetParent;
      
      var direction = prompt("Enter direction:\n left, right, up, down");
      switch (direction) {
        case 'left':
          player.style.left = (posL - 50) + 'px';
          console.log(player.style.left = (posL - 50) + 'px');
          break;
        case 'right':
          player.style.left = (posL + 50) + 'px';
          break;
        case 'up':
          player.style.top = (posT - 50) + 'px';
          break;
        case 'down':
          player.style.top = (posT + 50) + 'px';
          break;
        default:
          alert("you need to move!");
          break;
      }
      if (posT === posT1 && posL === posL1) {
        alert("YOU WIN!!!");
        return; // gets out of a loop
      }
      window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```